# Cannot find paypal payment buttons creation on sandbox

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have two sandbox paypal accounts: buyer and business(seller).
Recently i added a generated html from paypal as "Buy Now" button and it seems to work great.

Now i want to add sandbox button to test the process but after logged in to my sandbox account i cannot see any option to create payment button like had in my regular account.

I already read the paypal developer docs for sandbox but i do not see the "Create paypal button" anywhere.

It sounds to me like a simple issue and i cannot figure out why it is not easy to find.

Comment: you don't have to create any button you just have to update your client id and secret key and the live link to sandbox, and you're good to test it on sandbox

Comment: host: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
    mode: 'sandbox',//sandbox or live
    client_id: 'client_id_from_paypal',
    client_secret: 'client_secret_from_paypal'

Comment: I think you are talking on something else.
I asked about the button PayPal generate for you as an html elements.
In this button there is not client id and secret.

Answer (score 6):

You can access the PayPal button creator/manager from the Profile settings in the sandbox account. I've also included the direct link below:

Create a new button: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer

Manage existing saved buttons: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-management

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

After login sandbox.paypal.com, open this link: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer directly, you will see the create button page.