# How to test a production Paypal button?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a simple Paypal payment button:

[image]

on production of my e-commerce website. It works. Many customers have already bought items with it.

But now I'd like **to see exactly the payment workflow from a buyer's point of view, from the start, until payment successful + IPN mail + auto-redirect to payment-success page, etc.**

Paypal sandboxing seems [incredibly complex](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/paypal-here/sandbox-testing/using-sandbox-accounts-when-testing/), one has to create a Developer account, then 2 sandbox accounts, a facilitator (?), a buyer one, etc.
It also seems that Paypal duplicates the real content, into a virtual sandbox button, etc. This is really complex.

All I want is to **try my already-working production PayPal-button** with a single sandbox buyer account. How to do that?

**Is there a way to test a production Paypal  button with a sandbox account (with, say, 10000€), and to proceed to the payment like would do a real customer?**

... instead of having to create 3 accounts (Developer + Buyer SandBox account + Seller SandBox account)

---

*PS: I've read many docs about sandboxing in Paypal docs, but they have very old docs (deprecated), some old docs, some new docs, some very new docs, + some of them in French with different content to English version, etc. I'm totally lost!*

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can test payment buttons I'm testing one of those right now.

At first it seems more complex that it needs to be, but all you need to know is that the sandbox system is a different enviroment, so the only way to test a sandbox payment button is a sanbox account.

Go to your developer dashboard, create 2 accounts, 1 for the seller (pick merchant account when creating this one), 1 for the buyer.

Log in to sandbox.paypal.com with the seller, create the button as you already did, set the ipn and all you need. Place the button in your site, now test your new button and when paying log in with the buyer (sandbox account) you previously created.

Comment: Thanks. Ok, but how to replicate exactly my production button into a sandbox button? Is there a "duplicate production button into sandbox button" feature? If not, how to be sure the button I'm testing in sandbox is exactly the same than the one in production?

Comment: Find create button view  @ https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer , thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33729430/2162226

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to test environment for paypal buttons. I sent a few messages to them asking the same thing. The only way to test that is get int touch with them through your account and tell your test user, then they won't charge you.

Here's a translation I received a few weeks ago:

> In this case, the Sandbox environment does not allow payment on PayPal
>   buttons because there is no sandbox system for buttons, only for email
>   integration or PayPal account API.
>
> In this case we recommend that we send a URL of the buttons or even
>   your site already with the buttons registered.
>
> That way any analyst can do the actual payment test for you.
>
> Our test balance is only R $ 50,00 reais, so the buttons can not
>   exceed this value with product price and freight.

Comment: *"There's no way to test environment for paypal buttons."*, oh really? I didn't know, do you have a source about this? 
Does this work to call them and ask for testing? How? Would they refund / cancel transaction?

Comment: @basj updated my question with message I received from them. If you don't believe me you can get in touch with them through your account.